# problems installing pyhull

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install pyhull via pip install pyhull, but I get a compiler error:
[image]

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you, please, copy-past the full log?

Comment: I only see warnings, not a compiler error. Those warnings are probably because of the use of the (Visual C++) compiler, which appears to do things a bit differently (headers file may be missing, since various functions appear to return a default int). You may need to provide appropriate (environment) settings of flags when installing.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice, I had cut the picture. I added the rest. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[`strtok_r()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r), [`fmemopen()`, and `open_memstream()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fmemopen) are POSIX functions and are not available on Windows by default. As the author [admits that they have not tried it on Windows yet](http://pythonhosted.org/pyhull/#getting-pyhull) you will need to port or find a port of pyhull to Windows.